# What are my public transport options in Tbilisi and further afield in Georgia

Tags: public-transport, transportation, georgia-country, tbilisi

What are the different transport options for getting around the city of Tbilisi, and travelling to the Svaneti region.

Comment: Any particular locations you would like to visit?  Without it your question is too broad.  In addition please review existing question on Tbilisi as well.

Comment: There's a metro, taxis, and marshrutkas in the city, there's marshrutkas and a couple of train lines only for going long distance. But you need to ask less broad questions, we're not going to go into the details of every kind of transport for the whole country.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a lot of questions!

**Should I hire a car or are there tours available to tourist areas?** 
You probably don't need a car, the public transport in Tbilisi is pretty efficient, and when it's not it's still interesting :-)

**Are there regular bus services?** 
Yes, there is a metropolitan bus service. Most locals use the minibuses that you have to wave down. If your Georgian is rusty, this isn't a great option, but a surprising number of drivers do speak English. You have to request a stop, and request it before you get on, otherwise you may get an unexpected tour of the city before you get off!

**and what is the rail network like?**
Clean and efficient. There's tons of kids acting like hoodlums, but in my experience they're harmless. Watch your stuff though!

კეთილ მგზავრობას გისურვებთ!